# ternary operator ?: is throwing errors about wrong arguments

Tags: if-statement, ternary-operator, pine-script

I'm trying to display a different time frame macd on a given time frame chart. so display 5 min macd on 1 min chart etc.

I've decided to accomplish that by multiplying a number 5 to the interval which is an integer and then turn that into a string and use that in the plot. 
This works fine since I don;'t have to change it every time I change the time frame of the chart from 1 to 10 min etc, and it will still display the longer time frame macd based on the multiple.

This following code works fine using the ternary operator ?:

```
//@version = 2
study(title="test")

source = close
fastLength = input(12, minval=1)
slowLength=input(26,minval=1)
signalLength=input(9,minval=1)

// res5 mutiplies the current interval which is an integer by a factor 5 and turns it into a string with the value of "interval*5" or "1D" depending on the value of interval*5

res5= interval*5 < 1440 ? tostring(interval*5) : "1D"

src5=security(tickerid, res5, close)

fastMA5 = ema(src5, fastLength)
slowMA5 = ema(src5, slowLength)

macd5 = fastMA5 - slowMA5
signal5 = sma(macd5, signalLength)
outMacD5 = security(tickerid, res5, macd5)

plot( outMacD5 ? outMacD5 : na, color= red)
```

But if I were to change it to have more conditions like below, the ternary operator fails.

```
//@version = 2
study(title="test")

source = close
fastLength = input(12, minval=1)
slowLength=input(26,minval=1)
signalLength=input(9,minval=1)

// res5 mutiplies the current interval which is an integer by a factor 5 and turns it into a string with the value of "interval*5" or "1D" depending on the value 9of inteval*5

//res5= interval*5 < 1440 ? tostring(interval*5) : "1D"

res5= interval*5 < 1440 ? tostring(interval*5) : interval >= 1440 and interval*5 < 2880 ? "1D":na

src5=security(tickerid, res5, close)

fastMA5 = ema(src5, fastLength)
slowMA5 = ema(src5, slowLength)

macd5 = fastMA5 - slowMA5
signal5 = sma(macd5, signalLength)
outMacD5 = security(tickerid, res5, macd5)

plot( outMacD5 ? outMacD5 : na, color= red)
```

That brings back the error

```
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: Error: Cannot call `operator ?:` with arguments (bool, literal__string, na); available overloads ...
```

Using the iff brings back the same error about the arguments being incorrect.

I could really use some help here. I'm so lost in using these conditional operators.

Any tips are helpful.

Comment: All branches of a ternary expression should have the same type.

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming. what does that mean that the ternary expression should have the same type?

Comment: What is `na`? ...

Comment: na is supposed to be something like nan. without the code throws an error. with it it works fine. it's like ignore whatever is before it if the condition doesn't meet. in iff statement, res5= iff(interval*5 < 1440, tostring(interval*5), iff(interval*5 >= 1440 and interval*5 < 2880,  "1D"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
res5= interval*5 < 1440 ? tostring(interval*5) : interval >= 1440 and interval*5 < 2880 ? "1D": ""
plotchar(res5=="5", "res5 test", "", location=location.top)
```

The `plotchar()` call will allow you to confirm `res5`'s value. Here it is being tested for "5", so you will be able to verify in the Data Window (doesn't print anything in the indicator's pane so it doesn't disturb scale) that its value is 1 -> true when you are on a 1min chart.

[Edit 2019.08.19 09:02 — LucF]
Your question was about the ternary not working, which the code above resolves. Following your comment, you also need a more complete function to calculate a multiple of the current timeframe in v2. Use this:

```
f_MultipleOfRes( _mult) => 
    // Convert target timeframe in minutes.
    _TargetResInMin = interval * _mult * (
      isseconds   ? 1. / 60. :
      isminutes   ? 1. :
      isdaily     ? 1440. :
      isweekly    ? 7. * 24. * 60. :
      ismonthly   ? 30.417 * 24. * 60. : na)
      // Find best way to express the TF.
    _TargetResInMin     <= 0.0417       ? "1S"  :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 0.167        ? "5S"  :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 0.376        ? "15S" :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 0.751        ? "30S" :
      _TargetResInMin   <= 1440         ? tostring(round(_TargetResInMin)) :
      tostring(round(min(_TargetResInMin / 1440, 365))) + "D"
```

See [here](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-do-i-define-a-higher-interval-that-is-a-multiple-of-the-current-one) for a use case, but don't use that function code as it's v4.

Comment: This works for 5 times the resolution (that is like looking at 5 min macd on 1 m in chart.) 

But if I wanted to look at 20 times the resolution, it will fail after 1 hr chart. 

res20= interval*20 < 1440 ? tostring(interval*20) : interval >= 1440 and interval*20 < 2880 ? "1D": "" 


that will give invalid value of 'resolution' argument (") in the 'security' function.


I'm basically trying to adapt this code here. 

https://www.tradingview.com/script/A8xLIiFb-Multi-Timeframe-MACD/

Comment: Something is wrong with this code or my own understanding of how to do the rsi on tradingview.


if I add the following and try to compare the plots, they're not the same. I'm not understanding how the fucntions are working, clearly. Can you help me out with that? The code below should do exactly the same thing your function does withthe new timeframe. of 5 min on 1 min chart, but the plots are not the same. 

src1 = close
src2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, f_multipleOfRes(resMult),close)

rsrc2 = rsi(src2, 14)
plot(rsrc2, color=color.blue)

Comment: You need the `rsi()` call to run in the `security()` call, so after you've defined your `rsrc2` variable, pass it to `security()` as in `src2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, f_multipleOfRes(resMult), rsrc2)`.

Comment: ok, I think I got it. For some reason rsi() has to be inside the security() otherwise the results is not accurate while the trend is the same. One more problem with the function. If I were to `src2 = security(tickerid, f_multipleOfRes(resMult), rsi(close, 14))` and  
`plot(src2, color=fuchsia, title="f_multipleOfRes(resMult)")` does not show the result of the function as the label off to the side.  https://imgur.com/1ZEiBer What's going on with that? it's a string, but it'snot accepted by the plot. My old code would allow the plot to show the multiple as what it is.

Comment: The plot's title is a string, so it's not executing a function call. The function's result is a string, so you can't plot it using v2; you can only test it's value, as in `plot(f_multipleOfRes(2)=="30"?1:0)` which will plot 1 if you are on a 15 min chart because the condition is true, and zero otherwise.

Comment: is there a way to do it v4? because it does the same thing even if i changed the version to 4 and change all the code to work in v4.

Comment: There's an example of using a v4 label to print current and target resolutions [here](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-do-i-define-a-higher-interval-that-is-a-multiple-of-the-current-one). If you consider the original question answered, you can click the check mark under the voting arrows for this answer.

Comment: what you did above is a workaround, but it still will label the plots as plots if I remove the titles in the plot command, obscuring the view on the right. but i guess that's a limitation of the tradingview. and putting the label as a bar.state was an ingenious deal to get a job done. i think there is enough stuff on here for people to make something of the initial question. i'm still struggling with understanding how to write a function in pinescript.  anyway i'll mark this thread as answered. i really appreciate all you've contributed. thank you very much for your time.

Comment: btw, i just checked, and i had to type the individual time frame as a string in the plot to make it show up as the label on the right hand side, i didn't make it automatically show up... my bad.

Comment: If you want examples of functions to help you learn, we are starting to feed the [PineCoders snippets](https://github.com/pinecoders/pine-utils/tree/master/snippets) with code. You'll eventually see functions of all sorts in there. No better way to learn than to study code from the top Pine coders. gl!